# spring mvc crud example without database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to create a CRUD system without database in spring mvc framework?
If possible then which way?
I made an application where i can save and update a single value but i need to save and update a list of value.

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB offers in memory DB, you can use it to do crud operations for your unit tests. You can maintain spring configuration for the Unit tests and another spring configuration for deployed code. The db configuration can be different for both, so, you run the data updates on the in-memory databse when running tests and actual database when deployed to server. Spring takes care of this seamlessly.
http://hsqldb.org/ spring boot has this [inbuild](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Other ways to test out your code is to using [mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) where you test your code on mock data/objects.

*Update*: there is something called [DBUnit](https://dzone.com/articles/database-unit-testing-dbunit), just found out, it can also help you test against fake db

Answer (score 0):

You Can recreate a CRUD operation using File Systems In Java using a File or Excel  as a Database and and then Using File Handling or Apache POI in order to Create Update or Delete.